# How to make an if statement that checks if a cookie is expired

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a program that needs to check for a cookie. When the cookie expires, I want it to display a prompt and alert something.

```js
 if (document.cookie == '' || document.cookie == null || document.cookie == undefined) {  
  var site = prompt("Please enter a valid url:", "http://");
  document.cookie = "url=;"
  document.cookie = 'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2030 00:00:00 GMT';
  alert("The cookie is expired.");
 }
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you search on google you will easily find some basic get/set functions,
Here is a [sample link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

then you could use this as below

```
if(getCookie(nameOfYourCookie) == "")
{
    //Show Alert,
    //Set cookie
}
```